# Are gravitons Goldstone bosons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking

This question is inspired by [Are Photons Goldstone Bosons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367291/are-photons-goldstone-bosons/522942#522942). And recently in [Generalized Global Symmetries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148), photon was interpreted as Goldstone boson for generalized symmetry (see also my answer for question about photons and [David Tong lectures](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html)).

Is such interpretation for massless spin 2 particles? What is corresponding global generalized symmetry? (But there is statement, that there aren't global symmetries in gravity)

(What about spin 3, 4 ... ? What about spin 1/2, 3/2 ...?)

Comment: The answer is yes, but to show it at the full non-linear level is a little too technical for a post here. You can find the details e.g. here https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6098 . For the linear used version of the spin 2 graviton (as well as the higher spins) it is much simpler to show that they may be thought as Goldstones, if I find time in the next few days I will post an answer.

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting. What do you think about interpretation through spontaneous breaking of some generalized symmetry?